# Investigating the change of a network / factorial structure over time

Tags: r, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, graph-theory, networks

I have several variables (questions from a questionnaire) that regroup into several factors (using factor analysis). However, I would be interested in knowing how this factorial structure changes depending on another numeric variable (in my case, time).

From what I understood, SEM would allow me to estimate the influence of this "modulator" directly on the latent variables. But I am not sure I can estimate its influence on the link between variables itself.

What statistical method could help me addressing my question? Thanks

Comment: What's the modulator? (What's a modulator? Do you mean moderator?)

Comment: A continuous variable that modulates / influences something else. From what I understood moderator is often used in the context of moderation analysis when one relationship is in fact "moderated" by another link. But in the end yes that's pretty close

Comment: You should look at longitudinal invariance.